# How long would it take for someone to pay off money?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If someone borrows \$500 and pays \$30 every 10 days, how long will it take them to pay the $500?

The following is what my thought process is:
distance: \$500 
velocity: \$30/10 days 
time: ? 
v = d/t
t = d/v
t = 500/3
t = 166.66667 days

Comment: That is correct if we assume several things... such as assuming that the final payment can be made early in the middle of the 10-day period and that there is no interest (*how banks and lenders make money off of loaning you money, the longer you are borrowing from them the more you owe*).  If you may only pay at the end of each 10-day period then perhaps round up to 170 days.  If you have to account for interest rates, then the formula will be more complicated (*but still very useful for the average person to know*).

Comment: It does feel a bit awkward to hear you refer to this as "distance" and "velocity" since we aren't really working with physical positions in space, but if it helps you internalize things then go ahead... its a fine enough metaphor.

Comment: It's a formula I remember from phyiscs class

Comment: If you have a problem like this, an answer like t = 166.66667 days so it gives  times  in seconds  and less, is not meaningfull, So the answer should be  either 160 days and  $20 after 10 more days, or 170 days the last payment only $20

Comment: You have an okay idea but you aren't paying the money off in a steady stream.  On day 160 you make you $16$ payment and have paid off $16\times 30 = 480$ dollars.  And you aren't going to pay off any more for $10$ days.  On day $166$ you ... don't pay anything as it is not a payment day.  The next payment day is day $170$ when you pay the final $20$ dollars.  So I'd say the answer is $170$ days.  I'd add an extra step $t= rnd(\frac dv)$ where $rnd$ is "round up to the nearest $10$"  So $t =rnd(\frac {500}3)=rnd(166\frac 23) = 170$.

Comment: That result is going to be consumed by another formula, not a human, which is why I left like that

Answer (score 0):

Using physics terms for money is awkward, so I like to think of it like this.

If we get \$$30$ on the $10$th day, then surely we'll have \$$60$ by the $20$th, \$$90$ by the $30$th, etc. Notice how $\frac{30}{10} = \frac{60}{20} = \frac{90}{30} = \dots$ all equal $3$, where the denominator represents the day we get paid and the numerator represents how much money we have on that day. We want to figure out the day (let's call it $t$) when we'll have \$$500$. Then we solve the equation

$$\$3 = \frac{\$500}{t}.$$

Solving for $t$ gives us approximately the $167$th day.

Therefore, it'll take us about $167$ days for that person to keep their end of the bargain.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.